# Меняется цвет у блока при обновлении страницы

Tags: css, css3, scss

На сайте у каждой кнопки в меню выставлен цвет фона. 
При нажатии на кнопку, цвет меняется и происходит переход на эту страницу.

Этой кнопке присваивается class="is-active" и для этого класса выставляется цвет нажатой кнопки.

Смущает тот момент, что после нажатия на кнопку и переходе на страницу, на долю секунды отображается первоначальный цвет, после цвет из is-active.

Как правильно сделать, что бы ничего не мигало и сразу подхватывало цвет is-active

Comment: а как вы делаете?

Comment: генерить нужный цвет/класс на серверной стороне. Если вы высталвяете цвет в js в событии готовности документа - то мелькать будет все равно, не этой машине дак на более медленной.

Comment: @Bogdan В  Drupal 8 создал меню, там автоматически проставляется класс выбранной странице